# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS бывает зависает

Tags: ubuntu

Компьютер зависает, примерно, при каждом 6-10 запуске или выключении.

- При запуске зависает приблизительно в тот момент когда я должен ввести пароль, бывает зависает когда пароль ввел и нажал энтер.
- При выключении зависает когда жму "Выключить": пропадает рабочий стол и на этом все, комп завис и не вырубается.

У меня:

- Ноутбук *MSI*
- Процессор: *AMD A10-5750M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 4*
- Графика: *Gallium 0.4 on AMD ARUBA*
- 64 битная ОСЬ
- На другом диске предустановлена винда 8.1

Никакие драйвера не качал, все драйвера по умолчанию стоят, которые предоставила сама *ubuntu*

Из программ:

- Хром
- Опера
- Xampp
- Скайп

и другие, что по умолчанию шли.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: какие действия вы предприняли для решения проблемы? просматривали ли логи syslog, messages, daemon, сообщения кольцевого буфера linux и т.п.?

Comment: К моему сожалению, я новичок в ubuntu и linex подобных систем. А где эти лог файлы расположены? Сейчас погуглю тогда

Comment: [Ubuntu зависает при загрузке — решение checking quotas…](http://blog.treeone.ru/ubuntu-zavisaet-pri-zagruzke-reshenie-checking-quotas/92/) -
вот всё что удалось найти. sudo e2fsck -y -f -c /dev/sda1 ну тут понятно нужно указать свою sda раз у тебя там есть "На другом диске предустановлена винда 8.1"

Comment: как и принято в операционной системе *gnu/linux*, эти лог-файлы можно найти в `/var/log`. кольцевой буфер *linux*-а можно просмотреть программой `dmesg` («красивый» вывод получается с опцией `-H`, если реализована в вашей версии дистрибутива).

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос не относится к тематике программирования.

Comment: @Владимир: ответ вполне относится к администрированию и настройке сложного ПО.

Comment: @Владимир, программирование - не единственная тема, по которой тут задают вопросы.